# Understanding how rpmbuild works

Tags: linux, build-process, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

It seems that the RPM logic is quite different from what I know already and I am having some issues understanding the *"RPM logic"*. For my work, I have to create a documentation on "How-to create a RPM package on Red Hat 5".

I'm used to Debian and it's derivatives (Ubuntu, and so on) and thus to *Debian packages* (aka. `.deb` files).

From what I read, it seems that ones need to be `root` to create a RPM package. While I understand why `root` could be required to *install* a package, I still don't understand why elevated privileges should be needed just to *create* one.

If I try to create a RPM package as a user, changing the `buildroot` it fails on the `%install`step because I don't have permission to write files into `/usr/bin`. Fair enough but... why does it want to copy my files into `/usr/bin` at this step?! I just want to create the package, not install it!

I'm sure I'm missing something here. Is there anyone who could give me at least a basic understanding of how `rpmbuild` works and why?

Comment: @bignose: I really meant to thank people you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/BuildingPackagesGuide) do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be root to build RPM packages. I recommend you to read [this two part article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The official [*Maximum RPM* book](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/) also has a chapter on **[Having RPM Use a Different Build Area](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html)**, which allows non-root users to build RPMs.